# Access parent window from User Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to access parent window from user control.

```
userControl1 uc1 = new userControl1();

mainGrid.Children.Add(uc1);
```

through this code I load `userControl1` to main grid.

But when I click on a button inside `userControl1` then I want to load another `userControl2` into `mainGrid` which is in main window?

Answer (score 78):

Have you tried

```
Window yourParentWindow = Window.GetWindow(userControl1);
```

Comment: yes i tried but then after how can load userControl2 into mainGrid ?

Comment: Window yourParentWindow = Window.GetWindow(userControl1);
yourParentWindow.mainGrid.children.add(new userControl2);

is this right code ?

Comment: yourParentWindow.mainGrid.Children.Add(new userControl2())

Answer (score 29):

This gets the root level window:

```
Window parentWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow
```

or the immediate parent window

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

Answer (score 4):

The only reason why the suggested

```
Window yourParentWindow = Window.GetWindow(userControl1);
```

didnt work for you is because you didn't cast it to the right type:

```
var win = Window.GetWindow(this) as MyCustomWindowType;

if (win != null) {
    win.DoMyCustomWhatEver()
} else {
    ReportError("Tough luck, this control works only in descendants of MyCustomWindowType");
}
```

Unless there **has to be** way more coupling between your type of windows and your control, I consider your approach bad design .

I'd suggest to pass the grid on which the control will operate as a constructor parameter, make it into a property or search for appropriate (root ?) grid inside any `Window` dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

Modify the constructor of the UserControl to accept a parameter of MainWindow object. Then pass the MainWindow object to the UserControl when creating in the MainWindow.

**MainWindow**

```
public MainWindow(){
    InitializeComponent();
    userControl1 uc1 = new userControl1(this);
}
```

**UserControl**

```
MainWindow mw;
public userControl1(MainWindow recievedWindow){
    mw = recievedWindow;
}
```

**Example Event in the UserControl**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mw.mainGrid.Children.Add(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help me guys. i got another solution

```
 ((this.Parent) as Window).Content = new userControl2();
```

this is perfectly works

Comment: Caution: here you assume that your control's parent will always be a Window instance.

Answer (score -1):

Make a static instance of main window ,you can simply call it in your user control:

See this example:

**Window1.cs**

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _Window1 = this;
        }
        public static Window1 _Window1 = new Window1();

    }
```

**UserControl1.CS**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void AddControl()
        {
           Window1._Window1.MainGrid.Children.Add(usercontrol2)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution will not work if there are more than one instance of the window in question open at a time. I see in your comment that you refer to the "Main window" for this to work (which I guess there would only ever be one of). However, it should be noted that this does not scale to all window types.